# jquery ajax bootsrap about modal pop up

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

When I click button with class `.btn-edit` the modal appears, but when i submit the `ajax` request after that if I click the button for modal the modal doesn't show. I need to refresh the page for it to work again.

```
 $(".btn-edit").click(function(){
    $('#edit-profile').modal('show');
});


$(".update-form").submit(function(s){
    s.preventDefault();

    var website_name = $('input[name=website_name]').val();
    var website_url = $('input[name=website_url]').val();
    var type = $('#type option:selected').val();
    var category = $('#category option:selected').val();
    var sells = $('input[name=sells]').val();
    var location = $('input[name=location]').val();
    var payment = $('input[name=payment]').val();
    var description = $("textarea#message").val();

    $('#edit-profile').modal('hide');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "advertiser/update",
        data: {
            _token: token, 
            website_name: website_name, 
            website_url: website_url, 
            type: type, 
            category: category, 
            sells: sells, 
            location: location, 
            payment: payment, 
            description: description
        },

        success: function(data) {
            $('.wrapper').html(data);
        }
        ,
        error: function(data) {

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: Can you paste the html? Is #edit-profile inside .wrapper tag?

Comment: @aarjithn yes the class wrapper div cover all div in page Im using laravel the wrapper tag on my layout.main [link](http://laravel.io/bin/YyBmV) sorry for late reply

Comment: console error log: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: Work out what line the error is on then work out why it is an error